# SSL certificate incorrectly installed on nginx web server (Django web app)

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

My Django website is perfectly reachable at example.com. The webserver is nginx (reverse proxy) with gunicorn as the upstream. `netstat -4plunt` shows that `nginx` is listening on `port 443`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19745/nginx
```

I've installed a CA-authority signed SSL certificate, and my goal is to get my website to load both over `https` and `http` (no redirection).

Yet `https://example.com` never finishes loading for me on my Firefox browser, just going on endlessly (note that `http://example.com` works perfectly). And if I look into `/var/log/nginx/error.log` right after that, I see **no new errors logged**. *Does this mean the request didn't even reach nginx, even though it was listening on port 443?*

If I test it on https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker, I get:

> No certificates were found

Can you identify **what my problem could be**, or if not that, at least **how can I start diagnosing it**? My `nginx` virtual host file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myserver.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    charset utf-8;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {

        root /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {

        root /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/;
    }

    location /status {
        stub_status on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow 40.114.247.165;
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffers 8 24k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        include proxy_params;
        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_whitelist.rules;
        proxy_pass          http://unix:/home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/myproject.sock;

    }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/templates/;
   }
}
```

`proxy_params` contains:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

*Note: Please ask for more information if necessary. E.g. gunicorn.conf, etc.*

---

In `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`, I have:

```
*filter
# Allow all outgoing, but drop incoming and forwarding packets by default
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Custom per-protocol chains
:UDP - [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:ICMP - [0:0]

# Acceptable UDP traffic

# Acceptable TCP traffic
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Acceptable ICMP traffic

# Boilerplate acceptance policy
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Drop invalid packets
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# Pass traffic to protocol-specific chains
## Only allow new connections (established and related should already be handled)
## For TCP, additionally only allow new SYN packets since that is the only valid
## method for establishing a new TCP connection
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP

# Reject anything that's fallen through to this point
## Try to be protocol-specific w/ rejection message
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

# Commit the changes
COMMIT

*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

Comment: would it be a problem so split http / https config up, so that your website will still be reachable over http and https? do you write log files, your config doesn't seem to.. would be really helpful to get an idea what's going wrong.

Comment: @semm0: no, what exactly do you suggest in that regard? Feel free to write an answer. Why I haven't done that thus far is because, isn't doing it my way *supposed to work* too? (it's in nginx's own docs) I even tried `#listen80`, and purely tried connecting with https. That didn't load either. I feel something's up with how I've set up my `https` code. Maybe in your answer, you could give me your own sample config?

Comment: yes I can give you an example config. Please allow me to take lunch, expect an answer during the next two hours. then we can see where the errors occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I separated http/https part in my config example:

```
upstream myproject_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).
  # Check if the path to myproject.sock is correct!

  server unix:/home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/myproject.sock; fail_timeout=0;
}


server {

    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;

    # define if needed
    #client_max_body_size 4G;

    charset utf-8;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    # write error log file for http errors:
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example-http-error_log info;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /webapps/hello_django/media/;
    }

    location / {

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        #proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffers 8 24k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;

        # additional proxy parameters
        include proxy_params;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://myproject_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/templates/;
    }
}


server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myserver.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    charset utf-8;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    # write error log file for https errors:
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example-https-error_log info;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /webapps/hello_django/media/;
    }

    location / {

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        #proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffers 8 24k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # additional proxy parameters
        include proxy_params;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://myproject_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/templates/;
    }
}
```

Comments in this config are from [this source](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). I tried to adapt the settings you provided in your question. Please check if they are correct.

Comment: you're welcome. error logging is currently disabled, as by your config. you can enable it adding `error_log  /var/log/nginx/example-http-error_log info;` to your http block and `error_log  /var/log/nginx/example-https-error_log info;` to the https block. Then you can see what happens for http/https.

Comment: edited my answer and added the error log part for http/https.

Comment: I noticed your comment that you're unsure what `proxy_params` is. I've added that in the question too. Full disclosure.

Comment: ok edited my answer, removed two lines as they were duplicate with the information on proxy_params. thx for info.